# Hide li elements if href is empty

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have:

```
<ul class="webServicesURLS">
            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="restURL" runat="server" Text="REST" /></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="bboxURL" runat="server" Text="BBox" /></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="esbURL" runat="server" Text="ESB" /></li>
</ul>
```

In which the href link is added in code behind if such link is available in database.
I want to hide the `<li>` that don't have any href links added to them, using jQuery, and in case I don't have any href links in them then hide the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) with a [has attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector and the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, respectively:

```
$("li:not(:has(a[href]))").hide();
$("ul:not(:has(li:visible))").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$("li:not(:contains(a))").hide();
```

**Update**
It shouldn't be `:contains` but `:has`, my mistake. The following is correct:

```
$("li:not(:has(a[href]))").hide()
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4AJRb/).

Comment: The example you are providing is checking if there is no an <a> tag inside the <li>. What I want is to check if the <a> tag (always present) contains an href link. I modified yours to $("li:not(:contains(a[href]))").hide(); but the it hides all if just one doens't contain an href.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function() {

```
if(!(".webServicesURLS li a").attr("href")){
    $(this).parent().hide();
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$("ul.webServicesURLS li:not(:has(a))").hide();
$("ul.webServicesURLS:not(:has(li))").hide();
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e49cs/